# Exporting dataframe from Python to excel csv

Tags: excel

I want to export my data from python to an excel spreadsheet (csv).

My data looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oUh9K.png).

My code:

```
export_csv = Reference_all.to_csv('d:\\11221161\\Desktop\\sam\\fichiers\\donnees\\export_dataframe2.csv',  index=False, header=True)
```

...and it gives me [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XrebL.png).

So it gives me all the data put into one column which is not what I want.

How can I keep the formatting I have under python?
Thanks!

Comment: Hey King, have you played around with the [to_excel command?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

Comment: Yes, but I can't find how to separate the data. It keeps exporting it into only one column

Comment: Have you tried specifying a sep=","? It should be the default, but it looks like it is not separating properly. Consider changing the separator to another symbol, like | or _ and see what happens. I have gotten a problem like this before and fixed it by using sep="_".

Comment: Judging from your pic, the `NaN` is just being placed there as a placholder, you need to manually replace the `NaN` with something like a space or a string.

Comment: I also tried exporting it in xlsx using  export_xslx = Reference_all.to_excel('d:\11221161\Desktop\sam\fichiers\donnees\export_dataframe.xlsx',na_rep='NaN',  index=False, header=True, merge_cells=False) but it was too hard for my computer and it shut down (I have a very large dataset)